# Get the exception folder to a listbox C#

Tags: c#, exception

I'm creating a method to handle directory and file exceptions.

I have listed all the directories and subdirectories of the C: \ Users \ folder

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\Users\\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

Some folders are protected by windows, and when you run a command for those folders it gives us an exception.

If there is any possible, How can I save the folder that returned the exception to a listbox when the exception happens? thanks

Comment: Create a list<string>, and iterate through all directories, for each directory, add a try-catch to handle the exception, and log the directory name to the list<string>. Then you will get a list of directories that will throw exceptions.

Comment: Do you only want the first folder with an exception or do you want all folders with exceptions?

Comment: Ben I need All folders with exceptions, Eldeniz It's the param to get all directories and subdirectories from a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you catch the Exception the Message will tell you the folder that threw the exception in the format of 
Access to the path 'C:\Users\SomeFolder' is denied.

you just need to remove the static text, the simplest way is(you maybe able to find a more stylish way to do this, but you get the idea):

```
        try
        {
            listBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\Users\\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            SomeListBox.Items.Add(ex.Message.Replace("Access to the path '", "").Replace("' is denied.", ""));
        }
```

EDIT: if you want to traverse all the folders and keep going you might want to take a look at recursion. you could slightly modify the above code to make it a function.

```
void getDirectories(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            listBox1.Items.AddRange(directories);
            foreach(string directory in directories)
            {   
                getDirectories(directory);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            SomeListBox.Items.Add(ex.Message.Replace("Access to the path '", "").Replace("' is denied.", ""));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will stop iterating after the first exception.

Comment: Please read the question "How can I save the folder that returned the exception", the OP is not asking about Folders. he explicitly asks for the one that is throwing the exception.

Comment: There's reading a question of a non-native speaker and taking it literally, and there's understanding what they're trying to to. They want to enumerate all directories, including the ones that are inaccessible.

Comment: sorry about that, I'm a non-native speaker as well and I tend to not to presume too much o what other might want, I already added another answer that might help.

Comment: Worked, Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want all folders with exceptions:

You can use the method with the following call:

```
List<DirectoryInfo> list = GetDirectories(new DirectoryInfo(@"root directory"), 0, 2);
```

I've implemented a max level, because in a deep structure it could take a long time before the search is done. If you don't need it, just remove the unnecessary lines of code ;)

```
List<DirectoryInfo> GetDirectories(DirectoryInfo di, int level, int maxLevel)
{
    List<DirectoryInfo> exceptionList = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
    foreach (DirectoryInfo directoryInfo in di.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
        try
        {
            DirectorySecurity directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
            if (level + 1 < maxLevel)
            {
                exceptionList.AddRange(GetDirectories(directoryInfo, level + 1, maxLevel));
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            exceptionList.Add(directoryInfo);
        }
    }
    return exceptionList;
}
```

Comment: It worked very well, but I will use the code from the another answer because It's more simple and fast to understand (not for me, I am making a open source program). Thank You for your time anyways.